# How tall should the slime minion fence be?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

So in Hypiexl Skyblock, I want to make a [slime minion](https://hypixel-skyblock.fandom.com/wiki/Slime_Minion). But I'm not sure how high the surrounding fences should be to prevent the slimes from escaping or suffocating in the blocks above it. The wiki link doesn't provide any other information too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the real  [wiki](https://wiki.hypixel.net) you can see a better visualisation of the 'ideal placement' menu, which you can also see in game. For a slime minion it has a number 4 in the fence slots meaning 4 high.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You should link the actual page containing the information you are quoting, not just the generic home page.